# Which variant of operator [] of std::vector gets called when the following line is executed and why?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, rvalue, lvalue

According to [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) Operator[] of std::vector has 2 variants

1. `reference operator[] (size_type n);`
2. `const_reference operator[] (size_type n) const;`

When we execute the following line which of the above variant gets called?

```
std::vector<int> vlist;
vlist[0] = 7;
```

My thought, the 1st variant should not be called as I am assigning rvalue to an non-const lvalue reference, the way `int& x = 7;` is illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `vlist` is non const, the first option (the non-const one) will get called.

The compiler looks for the most correct method to call.

Only `const` methods can be called on const objects. In case you have a non-const object, both const and non-const methods of the object can be called.

If there are both const and non-const implementations of a method, the correct one will be called, depending on the constness of the object itself.

Your example of `int& x = 7` is indeed illegal but it's not the case presented above (`vlist[0] = 7`). You are right that one cannot declare a reference to an `rvalue`. But assigning an `rvalue` to a reference object is perfectly fine.

Comment: "But assigning an rvalue to a reference object is perfectly fine." -- This is where my confusion was. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first variant is called. `int &x = 7;` is not legal because this is a definition. But `int &x = y; x = 7;` is perfectly fine. And here you get already constructed reference so assignment is OK. Also assigning const to non-const is not a problem, because you can create non-const copy of const;

Comment: "already constructed reference" -- I missed this part. The question looks idiotic now.